# Creating a Cylindrical Mask of a 3D Image using Numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, masking

I attempting to create  cylindrical mask for a 3D image in order to remove the green circle seen around the image.

With the script I have written I am able to mask the image but I am cutting out a large portion of the image in the end. I want to create a mask that does not lose the central image but removes the circle.

I think the issue is that the mask I am generating is too small, would the solution be to adjust the size of meshgrid object I made with np.linspace?

> ```
> image,header = nrrd.read(image) #load image 
>
>
> s = image.shape
>
> x = np.linspace(-100, 100, s[0])
> y = np.linspace(-100, 100, s[1])
> z = np.linspace(-100, 100, s[2])
> x,y,z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z) # Meshgrid based on image size 
>
> mask = (x)**2 + (y)**2 <= (z)**2 # Cylindrical mask to remove circle 
> print("masked")
>
> maskimg = plt.imshow(mask[:,:,400],cmap="gray")
> plt.show()
> z_masked = np.multiply(mask,image) # Apply mask to image 
> zimg_masked = plt.imshow(z_masked[:,:,400])
> plt.show()
> ```

[Image of object I am trying to mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DI93.png)

[Result from my current script, the image appears to be cutoff losing a lot of vital information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdLhG.png)

Comment: But its a 2D image, so you need a doughnut shaped 2D mask rather than a 3D cylindrical mask. Isn't it ?

Comment: It is a 3D image. The picture I posted is just a 2D slice however.

Comment: you yourself suggested a solution. did you try it? why don't we see how the code _fails_? you are asking about some kind of failure, right? demonstrate it.

Comment: x²+y²≤z² is not a cylinder equation, tho. It's a cone.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have included the result that I am getting

Comment: yeah, @chrslg's insight would explain that.

Comment: Would the equation be (x-xo)^2+(y-yo)^2 = (z-zo)^2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> ```
> image,header = nrrd.read(image)
>
> s = image.shape
>
> mask = np.zeros_like(image,dtype=bool)
> center = (s[1] // 2, s[0] // 2, s[2] // 2)
> radius = 900  # radius in pixels
>
> x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(mask.shape[1]), np.arange(mask.shape[0]), np.arange(mask.shape[2]))
> mask = (x - center[2])**2 + (y - center[1])**2 + (z - center[0])**2 <= radius**2
> masked_image = image * mask
> plt.imshow(masked_image[:,:,400]);plt.show()
> ```

This seems to do what I want. I have added lines of code that automatically creates the mask at the center of the image. I also included a variable that will add a radius that can be defined across the whole image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).